# if fi [: too many arguments

Tags: bash, if-statement, arguments

Is there any problem with this script ?

```
if [ grep -q "#<filter>" /etc/hosts ] &&  [ grep -q "#</filter>" /etc/hosts ] ; then
 echo "exist"
fi
```

The error it shows is :

```
[: too many arguments
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are wrapping ordinary commands in the `[` syntax. This is not valid. The `[` token is actually a command, which interprets its arguments as a very limited expression language for doing string and numeric comparisons, and conditions on files and directories, such as tests having to do with type, existence, timestamps.

In the shell syntax, you can wrap a sequence of commands in `(...)` parentheses. The effect of this is to run the enclosed commands in a new child process. You can also group commands with braces to create a group command.

The `&&` and `||` commands have equal precedence; it is not like the analogous sequencing in the C language. Basically if you have a command, you can tack on another command using `|| another command` or `&& another command`. The `||` operator means: run the following command if everything to the left of here failed. "Do this, **or else** if it fails, do this". The `&&` operator means: if everything succeeded so far, also do the following.

If you want logic like `(A || B) && (C || D)` -- in other words, A, B, C and D must be run in that sequence, and you want at least one command in each `||` group to succeed, that can be done with braces like this:

```
{ A || B; } && { C || D; }
```

or with parentheses, if you don't mind forking child processes just to control evaluation. Note that the semicolons are required in the group command syntax; or else newlines must be used, and there must be whitespace around the braces.

Without the braces, `A || B && C || D` means the same thing as `A || { B && { C || D; } }`: it is essentially right associative with equal precedence.  And, by the way, the `&` operator (backround job) has a lower precedence `A || B && C || D &` means to put the whole darn thing in the background, not only `D`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this using a better [boolean approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_and_false_%28Unix%29)

```
if grep -q "#<filter>" /etc/hosts &&  grep -q "#</filter>" /etc/hosts; then
 echo "exist"
fi
```

No need test command ( `[ ]` ) there

`[ ]` expect an expression with a switch, like `[ -s file ]` or a single variable like `[ $SHELL ]`, but not a full command line like you attempt.

Comment: To clarfiy: the problem is that `[ ... ]` looks like syntax, but is actually another name for the `test` command. There are no brackets needed around the condition of an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need only 1 condition using `lookahead regex` like this:

```
 grep -qP "#<filter>(?=[\s\S]*#</filter>)" && echo "exists"
```

Comment: It's not a AND but a OR boolean logic here. That means that doesn't check both the 2 strings but only existence of one

Comment: @sputnick: `&&` means grep was successful.

Comment: I know, what I mean is not for this part but your regex. This is not what OP asked.

Comment: I think what sputnick means is that it's not an OR but an AND logic, right?